# Purpose and usage of the optional parameter (additional) of the method data_for from the data_magic class

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to understand how and what for to use the optional parameter (additional = {}) of the data_for method, included in the cheezy/data-magic gem:

```
  def data_for(key, additional={})
    if key.is_a?(String) && key.match(%r{/})
      filename, record = key.split('/')
      DataMagic.load("#{filename}.yml")
    else
      record = key.to_s
      DataMagic.load(the_file) unless DataMagic.yml
    end
    data = DataMagic.yml[record]
    raise ArgumentError, "Undefined key #{key}" unless data
    prep_data data.merge(additional).clone
  end
```

Could someone please explain it to me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`additional` is used with [`Hash#merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) to override the values of same keys.

With empty hash, `Hash#merge` do nothing; if you don't specify anything for `additional` parameter, the `data_for` method will just use configuration from file.

---

```
data = {min: 5, max: 10}
data.merge({})  # empty
# => {:min=>5, :max=>10}
data.merge({max: 15})  # non-empty
# => {:min=>5, :max=>15}
```